# What will happen when this program runs? Will a stack overflow or heap overflow happen?

Tags: java

```
public class LinkedList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while(true)
        {
            new LinkedList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you start it and see?

Comment: Magic will happen !!!! **Abra ka Dabraa**

Comment: You will receive stack overflow exception

Comment: @hurix - Nope.. He will most probably get a `OutOfMemoryError`. He has only one stack frame. So he cannot get `StackOverflowError`

Comment: Why would you expect any sort of error? It'll keep creating new LinkedList instances that will just immediately go out of scope and be eligible for garbage collection. I'd expect this to just run forever. But I agree with @kocko - run it and tell us what happens.

Answer (score 0):

There's no recursion and no cycle of methods calling each other in an infinite loop, so the call stack will not grow much, and there's no reason for a StackOverflowError.

You might get out of memory error if your while loop creates many `LinkedList` instances quicker than the Garbage Collector frees them.